# How to implement MenuItem with InputGesture in an Avalonia MVVM Application?

Tags: c#, mvvm, avaloniaui, avalonia

I need a Menu with InputGesture like in the picture here: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/3602

Starting in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 with a new Avalonia MVVM Application,
I try to set up the XAML in Visual Studio to achieve this:

```
<MenuItem Header="New" InputGesture="CTRL + N" />
```

This line then results in the error message:

```
Unable to resolve suitable regular or attached property InputGesture on type Avalonia.Controls:Avalonia.Controls.MenuItem
```

I found a working sample here:
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/XamlControlsGallery

I'd try to build my Solution and Project based on that example to get it working.
But I would prefer being able to implement it on a new Avalonia MVVM Application build from scratch with Visual Studio.
Hints are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being the new features are not documented in [Avalonia Docs](https://avaloniaui.net/docs/), it may be useful for others to see my findings.
My goal was to create menus with shortcuts containing numbers (e.g. `Alt+0`).
In pure WPF (without Avalonia) the value `"Alt+0"` can be assigned to the tags representing a menu with shortcut.
In Avalonia however the values must correspond to the `enum Key` in [Key.cs](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Input/Key.cs).
 Otherwise the mentioned example menu would display `Alt+None` instead of `Alt+0`, and command binding wouldn’t work as expected.
This is an example XAML line to display the menu and bind the command as desired:

```
<MenuItem Header="Menu 0" InputGesture="Alt+D0" HotKey="Alt+D0" Command="{Binding Alt0Command}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`InputGesture` is available starting with `0.10.0-preview1`, it's not available in the stable `0.9.x` branch. XamlControlsGallery is using the preview version.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was it. I did install the 0.10.0-preview1 for another project before and thought the new project was also created with this version, but apparently the Visual Studio extension uses still the old version for new projects.